# PHP Is there any better way to create this new array?

Tags: php, arrays, key

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($keyListArray); $i++) {
      $newArray[$i] = $myArray[$keyListArray[$i]];
  }

//structure of arrays are as follows  
//$keyListArray = array (1,4,5);  
//$myArray = array(1=>array('hello', 4, 56, 7))
```

Comment: `$myArray($keyListArray[$i])` is $myArray a callback function ?

Comment: If `$myArray` is an array, then it looks like you have a syntax error in your example. It should be `$myArray[$keyListArray[$i]]`

Comment: Thanks, I'm really sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just trying to de-key `$keyListArray`, right? Try

`$newArray = array_values($keyListArray);`

`array_values()` returns all the values from the input array and indexes numerically the array. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

-- Edit for new info

You have some parenthesis mixed up with square brackets - that's what has confused everyone. You don't really need the $i to specify the keys since they will be consistent and numerical by default. The way you're doing it is fine, but a foreach will make things a bit shorter.

```
foreach ($keyListArray as $key) {
  $newArray[] = $myArray[$key];
}
```

Comment: no I dont think I'm trying to do that, I'm just trying to get a sub array of the existing array, using the specific keys of interest in `$keyListArray` But thank you!

Comment: You have parentheses where you need square brackets to access that existing array. Please see my changes.

Answer (score 3):

```
 foreach($keyList as $key)
    $newArray[] = $myArray[$key];
```